# Consulta para obtener horario

Tags: mysql

Me han pedido consultar cuando el horario sea menor a 5 horas, y nos dan como dato los horarios así, tenemos valores **hora_inicio y hora_fin**:

Mi código es :

```
/* !! 14.- Obtener los nombres, apellidos y teléfonos de los fisioterapeutas 
  que trabajen menos de 5 horas al día y estén trabajando actualmente.*/
  
  SELECT numero_trabajador_fisio, nombre, apellidos, telefono, especialidad

  FROM fisioterapeuta, profesionales

  WHERE estado = "trabajando" ;
```

Y lo que nos dan en el ejercicio es:

Registros:

> INSERT INTO profesionales VALUES('00003','45362198P','Fisioterapia
> ginecológica','Laura', 'Ortiz García','950324957',
> 'Trabajando','10:30:00','14:30:00');
>
> INSERT INTO profesionales VALUES('00004','89311145M','Fisioterapia
> traumatológica','Rafael', 'García Salcedo','950259011',
> 'Despedido','11:30:00','15:30:00');
>
> INSERT INTO profesionales VALUES('00005','92113355H','Fisioterapia
> pediátrica','Macarena', 'Fernández Sánchez','950663344',
> 'Trabajando','16:30:00','22:30:00');

Comment: Hola Matuto, en tu posteo no hay pregunta, deberías adjuntar tu código como texto, y aclarar cual es el problema y/o duda que te genera, gracias.

Comment: En principio están mal tus sentencias, no indicas a que campo harás los insert solo muestras los valores. Explica mejor tu problema y agrega el intento que haz realizado, de lo contrario cerraran tu pregunta.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia si values va contra todos los campos, y no tenes campos automaticos (por ejemplo un autonumerico), no es necesario especificar los campos.

Comment: Y cual es tu problema??? esa es la descripcion del ejercicio que tenes que resolver... que cosa no sabes hacer? restar 2 horarios?

Comment: @gbianchi si, no se como comparar los horarios para que sea menos de 5 horas

Comment: no se comparan.. se restan.. y comparas la diferencia.. nada mejor que la documentacion para eso!!!! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Mi comentario era para saber cual era el nombre de los campos de fecha y hacer el select, pero @gbianchi ya te dio la orientación.

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo algunas pruebas te dejo dos ejemplos para que te orientes, esto utilizando **TIMESTAMPDIFF**, [puedes leer mas aqui](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php).

La primer sentencia te devuelve la diferencia entre el lapso de lashoras, esto lo puedes hacer con **horas, minutos, segundos** especificandolo en la expresión.

**Ejemplo 1**: Genera una tabla con todos los horarios y el campo que muestra la diferencia como *horas_laboradas*.

> select hora_inicio,hora_fin,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,hora_inicio,hora_fin) AS horas_laboradas FROM test

Resultado:

| hora_inicio | hora_fin | horas_laboradas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11:30:00 | 15:30:00 | 4 |
| 16:30:00 | 22:30:00 | 6 |

**Ejemplo 2**: Obtiene los datos que en el lapso de tiempo sea menor o igual a 5 horas.

> select * FROM test where TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,hora_inicio,hora_fin) <= 5

Resultado:

| hora_inicio | hora_fin |
| --- | --- |
| 11:30:00 | 15:30:00 |

Dime si te sirvió.

**NOTA:** Modifica el nombre de los campos o tablas que correspondan a la tuya.